# Creating an object on touch

Tags: android, class, touch

I am very green at Android and programming in general. So I am asking to guide me about what information should I look for.
I want my app to create an object when the screen is touched, so this object appears under the finger. Right now I managed to create a button, but I need a special object, something like a note with a title which can be moved(dragged) and pressed. Should I write my own class for it?

So please tell me what should I read to achieve my goals?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) which acts like any other `View` but allows you to draw on top of its surface. Search for tutorials that show how to draw on a `SurfaceView` using the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

Egor's answer is good. You can also use a `FrameLayout` to do the trick. In a FramLayout each added child is drawn on top of the previous one, you can use this. First child should be a ViewGroup you want to be drawing on top of e.g. `RelativeLayout` and the second child would be the custom view that draws stuff when touched.